# Getting address parts out of address string

Tags: algorithm

I have german adresses like this

```
Birkenweg 13 51491 Overath
Emil-Hoffmann-Str. 13 50996 Köln
Rolandstr. 65 50677 Köln
Markusplatz 35 50968 Köln
Bonner Str. 245 50968 Köln
Aachener Str. 1590 50858 Köln
Viersener Str. 122 50733 Köln
Bergische Landstr. 219 51375 Leverkusen
Josef Gladbach Platz 81-100 50259 Pulheim
Hauptstr. 769 51399 Burscheid
Bielsteiner Str. 117-119 51674 Wiehl
```

whereas for instance in

```
Birkenweg 13 51491 Overath
```

I want to sort into those fields

```
Birkenweg = street
13 = house number
51491 = postcode
Overath = city
```

and in

```
Emil-Hoffmann-Str. 13 50996 Köln
```

it's

```
Emil-Hoffmann-Str. = street
13 = house number
50996 = postcode
Köln = city
```

and in

```
Josef Gladbach Platz 81-100 50259 Pulheim
```

it's

```
Josef Gladbach Platz = street
81-100 = house number
50259 = postcode
Pulheim = city
```

Which reliable way do you suggest?

Comment: Too bad it looks like they are not [US Addresses](http://usaddress.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for 5 consecutive digits (as this seems to be the most reliable thing to find), e.g. using a regular expression. That gives you the post code and the city. Split the string there. Search for the house number at the end of the string before the post code. Note that it may contain letters, e.g. "Habsburgerstrasse 55a".

Similar to this:

```
function splitGermanAddress(s) {
    var result = {};
    var parts = s.split(/\d\d\d\d\d/);
    var address = parts[0];
    result.postcode = s.substr(address.length, 5);
    result.city = parts[1].trim();

    var houseNo = /\d+\s*[a-z]?(\s*\-\s*\d+\s*[a-z]?)?\s*$/i
    var match = address.match(houseNo);
    if (match) {
        result.houseNumber = match[0].trim();
        result.street = address.substr(
            0, address.length - match[0].length).trim();
    } else {
        result.street = address;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99Lzm/2/

Answer (score 2):

[**Google Reverse Geocoding API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) if you have the coordinates.

[**Google Geocoding API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) if you have the address.

Comment: Good idea, but I am talking thousands of addresses which may trigger the limits of that api. Also I do not have the GPS-coordinates, which is required for your approach.

Comment: Edited my answer, however if you have thousands of addresses, good luck, you my search other "geocoding API"s, this is the term you are looking for. Alternatively, you can buy API rate limits from Google, shouldn't be expensive.